# Запуск основной программы после закрытия заставки

Tags: c++, qt4

Использую достаточно медленный ARM контроллер. Поднял на нем линукс.

Перед запуском основной программы появляется заставка на 5 секунд. После происходит загрузка. Понятно что гиф анимация требует достаточно ресурсов ЦПУ, которых и так нет.

Проблема заключается в одновременном запуски конструктора и окна "mainwindow" и гиф анимации. Охота разделить их во времени, чтобы сначала была гиф анимация после запуск конструктора окна "mainwindow" и переход на основную программу.

Вот код, что сделал:

```
// Класс заставки
class Splash : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Splash() {
        processLabel = new QLabel();
        connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(emitFinished()));
        connect(&_temerMainWindow, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(emitShowMainWindow()));
    }

    // Показываем заставку и стартуем таймер
    void start() {
        movie = new QMovie("./image/Titul.gif");
        processLabel->resize(640,480);
        processLabel->setMovie(movie);
        processLabel->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        processLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        processLabel->setGeometry(QStyle::alignedRect(Qt::LeftToRight,Qt::AlignCenter,processLabel->size(),qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry()));
        movie->start();
        processLabel->show();
        _temerMainWindow.start(4500);
        _timer.start(5000);
    }
signals:
    // Сигнал завершения работы заставки
    void finished();
private slots:
    void emitFinished()
    {
        movie->stop();
        movie->deleteLater();
        processLabel->deleteLater();
       _timer.stop();
    }

    void emitShowMainWindow()
    {
        _temerMainWindow.stop();
        MainWindow w;  // Не хочет запускать окно MainWindow программа падает. В чем дело?
        w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        w.show();
        emit finished();
    }

private:
    QLabel *processLabel;
    QMovie *movie;
    QTimer _timer;
    QTimer _temerMainWindow;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Splash splash;
    splash.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Программа падает при вызове окна 'MainWindow'.

Comment: а вопрос в чем?..

Comment: Вопрос как стробировать во времени "mainwindow" и гиф анимацию?

Comment: почему не вынести анимацию из конструктора mainwindow и не запускать ее перед вызовом конструктора?

Comment: Да как можно  запустить гиф анимацию перед вызовом конструктора и дождаться ее завершения?

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: Что нужно добавить в мой код чтобы сначала запустить гиф анимацию подождать 5 секунд и после запустить конструктор?

Comment: Перенесите всю логику с анимацией в отдельный виджет - запускаете его, дожидаетесь завершение и запускаете `mainwindow`

Comment: Посмотрите, добавил в  вопрос более конкретную проблему. Почему-то, когда вызываешь слот с "MainWindow w; 
  w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  w.show();"  программа падает. НЕ понимаю почему.

Comment: причину этого уже следует искать в вашем классе `MainWindow`. Но я бы еще посоветовал вам подумать на архитектурой - очень уж это никрасиво смотрится, да еще и утечки памяти..

Comment: А где утечка памяти?

Comment: хотя нет, еще раз проверил, утечки памяти сдесь нет. НО! Вас самого не смущает как вы обращаетесь с `processLabel` и `movie`? Вы выделяете память под `processLabel` в конструкторе через `new` а освобождаете... в функции `emitFinished`... с помощью `deleteLater`... Насколько это очевидно по-вашему? Почему не использовать абсолютно стандартный и очевидный путь: выделить память в конструкторе и освободить в деструкторе? Или менее очевидный, но тем не менее стандартный для Qt: создать объект в конструкторе и присвоить ему родителя?

Comment: Я учту и перепишу. Вот знаете переношу "  MainWindow w;  // Не хочет запускать окно MainWindow программа падает. В чем дело?
  w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  w.show();"  В тело функции main и сразу все работает. А при вызове слота не хочет.

Comment: сдесь, возможно, проблема в ассинхронной обработке сигналов. В любом случае, что вы сами и подтвердили, проблема решается грамотным проектированием (вынести `MainWindow` за пределы слота - это разумное решение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш объект окна создается в локальной (стековой) памяти метода, поэтому когда метод завершает свою работу, то вся локальная память очищается, следовательно удаляется объект окна. Я предлагаю сделать немного по-другому.

Минимальный рабочий вариант с применением [QEvenLoop](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html):

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMovie>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QEventLoop>

// Класс заставки
class Splash : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Splash() :QObject() {
    }

    // Показываем заставку и стартуем таймер
    int exec() {
        // Класс QEventLoop нам нужен для создания локального бесконечного цикла  сообщений, запускаемого методом QEventLoop::exec(), в самом конце метода
        QEventLoop _loop;

        // Объекты movie и processLabel удалятся автоматически при завершении работы метода
        QMovie movie("./image/Titul.gif");
        QLabel processLabel;
        processLabel.resize(640,480);
        processLabel.setMovie(&movie);
        processLabel.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        processLabel.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        processLabel.setGeometry(
                    QStyle::alignedRect(
                        Qt::LeftToRight,
                        Qt::AlignCenter,
                        processLabel.size(),
                        qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry())
                    );
        movie.start();
        processLabel.show();

        // Одноразовый сигнал завершения показа заставки
        QTimer::singleShot(5000, &_loop, SLOT(quit()));

        // Метод _loop.exec() не завершит свою работу до тех пор, пока 
        // _loop не получит сигнал quit() (от таймера)
        return _loop.exec();
    }

};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Заставку создаем через указатель, чтобы после удалить его за ненадобностью и освободить память
    Splash* splash = new Splash();

    // Создаем и показываем заставку. Метод exec будет работать пока не получит сигнал
    // от внутреннего таймера о завершении цикла и выходе из него
    splash->exec();

    // Удаляем объект заставки - очищаем память
    splash->deleteLater();

    // Показываем главное окно приложения
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Дополнение 1.** Попытка избавления от "зеленого":

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow window;
    Splash* splash = new Splash();      
    splash->exec();    
    window.show();
    splash->deleteLater();    

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Дополнение 2.** Чуть более сложный вариант избавления от зеленого экрана

```cpp
// Класс заставки
class Splash : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Splash():
        movie("./image/Titul.gif")
    {
    }

    // Показываем заставку и стартуем таймер
    int exec() {
        // из метки и муви делаем поля класса
        // остальное оставляем как было

        // ...
    }

private:
    QMovie movie;
    QLabel processLabel;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Splash* splash = new Splash();
    splash->exec();

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    // Теперь у вас на экране должны быть и заставка, и окно

    // Следующая строка должна заставку скрыть и удалить
    splash->deleteLater();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Все работает хорошо. Еще вопросик, как можно понять что окно  MainWindow уже открыто и отображено? А то у меня получается заставка ---> зеленное окно ---> потом окно "MainWindow".  Зеленое окно примерно появляется на 500 мили секунд.

Comment: @zhilenkov а забить на зеленый экран нельзя? Скорее всего это так отрабатывает ваша графическая система, заменяя одно окно другим. Можно попытаться загрузить в память оба окна сразу, при этом вначале главное скрыть, а после заставки показать

Comment: Попытался сделать вот так не помогло. '    Splash* splash = new Splash();
    splash->exec();
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w.show();
    QTimer::singleShot(500, splash, SLOT(deleteLater()));'

Comment: @zhilenkov попробуйте как в **дополнении** в ответе. Если не получится сделаю другой вариант